# mkdir not working even though permission is set with umask in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory

Whenever a user is activated am trying to create a directory for each users. My application root has a directory called ***uploads*** and inside that am trying to create a folder.each time a user is created a mkdir command runs which is throwing me this error. Check the image for the error status[image]

Here is the code snippets to create a folder

```
if (!file_exists('./uploads/'.$consultancyid)) {
     $old = umask(0);
       mkdir('./uploads/'.$consultancyid, 0777,true);
     umask($old); 
  }
```

> Note the problem does not appear in any other hosting but comes in Godaddy
>   hosting only. What might be the appropriate solutions

Comment: Can you create dirs on another path?

Comment: the problem does not appear in other web server, its occurring in godaddy hosting

Comment: What user does the web-server run as? Does that user have full 'write' privileges for the entire directory path?

Comment: just for the directory gave a full privilege

Answer (score 0):

Try to get document root from server variable:

```
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/'.$consultancyid, 0777,true);
```

Comment: Thanks fixed it by setting permission on the hosting